# PHP Curl - Send Origin Headers With Request

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying send a curl request to a URL which requires HTTP_ORIGIN to be set, I have this so far...

```
$headers = array(
    'Origin: www.myorigin.com',
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER, true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Sample Request'
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

This is giving me an error on the server side of Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN so it doesn't look like it is passing the origin through.

Have I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You use coma `,` instead of `=>` into your array, so `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is a value of the array, instead of a key.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true, // << HERE
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers, // << HERE
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Sample Request'
));
```